# Java: Classes & Variables

Tags: java, variables, instance

I know how to create a variable/class members in java as i started learning since two months, however in the following code snippet the first, Private variable (**instance**) is created as follows:

private static **StaticBlockSingleton** instance;

#### Code snippet:

```
public class StaticBlockSingleton {

    private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;
    
    private StaticBlockSingleton(){}
    
    //static block initialization for exception handling
    static{
        try{
            instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured in creating singleton instance");
        }
    }
    
    public static StaticBlockSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    } }
```

Here when the private static variable(**instance**) is created why the Class name (**StaticBlockSingleton**) is used, What is this concept? How does it work.

Appreciate your guidance on this.

***Additional point:***

Additional point: i am not asking about the 'static' keyword here, i am asking about the class name used as type for the variable or method.

Is it very specific purpose to use the class name as the TYPE for the members (variable/methods)?

Suppose if we use String type for instance variable or getInstance() method, Still can't we achieve the singleton functionality since we will call the getInstance()?

Not sure if i am missing any concept here...

Comment: Read about the singleton design pattern. Even on [SO Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/2179/singleton/15446/singleton-java#t=201706261512554383906). Or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: You need to read about the keyword static and the constructor in Java, I suppose.

Comment: @GiladGreen, Thank you for the article, Yes it is singleton, but why do we need to use the class name (StaticBlockSingleton) before the method or variable like StaticBlockSingleton getInstance() and private static StaticBlockSingleton  instance; respectively.

Comment: "why the Class name (StaticBlockSingleton) is used" <- Thats the type of the variable. Same as your would write "String" to declare a field as type of String. A Class can have instances of itself as class members. For example think of a Class "Human" that contains another two Humans fields called "mother" and "father".

Comment: interesting.... why do you think that creating an instance of ***StaticBlockSingleton*** will throw a RuntimeException???

Comment: @UmadharM - that will be covered in the article.. But basically because you are defining a method that needs a return type..

Comment: The Java Tutorial covers declaration of variables and methods, both of which require a declared type (return type, for methods). You should read the Tutorial.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, That was real time object example given, Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @GiladGreen, Thank you for the reference, Yes it covers everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;
```

this is using a variable `instance` of the type `StaticBlockSingleton`

```
private StaticBlockSingleton(){}
```

this is declaring an empty constructor, and marking it private so only the class itself can make a new instance

```
//static block initialization for exception handling
static{
    try{
        instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured in creating singleton instance");
    }
}
```

this is a static initializer block that will run once when the class is loaded, and create an instance and assign it to the `instance` variable

the exception handling here is bad because you loose any information about why the exception occurred, which would be stored in `Exception e`, and in general it is better to try to be as specific as possible with even the Exception type (like `FileNotFoundException` instead of `IOException`)

the static initializer block is unnecessary because an empty constructor wont throw an exception, so the first line should be changed to

```
private static StaticBlockSingleton instance=new StaticBlockSingleton();
```

and delete the static initializer block.

finally

```
public static StaticBlockSingleton getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

this is an exposed public method to return the `instance` variable. because the class's constructor is private, and the instance is static, there is only one instance for your whole code base

Comment: Thank you for well explanation. More over, Since the constructor is private, We cant create an object externally. Hence we need to use the same classname as type for the respective class members. My understanding is correct now?

Comment: when you use the `static` keyword, it is stored with the class itself rather than a specific instance of the class, so  you have `StaticBlockSingleton.{static methods and members}` vs `{someInstance}.{non static methods and members}`

Answer (score 0):

As the given name to the variable implies:

```
private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;
```

What you are looking at is the sigleton pattern, which guarantees you that you only have a single instance of a specific class. Thats why the constructor is private:

```
private StaticBlockSingleton(){}
```

This forces the creation of the only instance of this class to come from within  it, in the static initializer:

```
    static{
        try{
            instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured in creating singleton instance");
        }
    }
```

So all other classes will only get the existing instance, with the `getInstance()` method, like so:

```
StaticBlockSingleton.getInstance().someMethod();
```

You can read more about it in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)